# Problem with GET Method (To Mongo DB) in Next JS 13 beta

Tags: mongodb, next.js

I am using Next JS 13 beta with Mongodb. The post method is working fine but the GET method is showing the result in body. I mean the

```
NextResponse.json(
  {
    message: products,
  },
  {
    status: 200,
  }
);
```

is not working. Although it is showing the perfect result in console.

I'm not too familiar with Next JS 13 Beta.

Help me to show the result when I put the GET request in postman `http://localhost:3000/api/products`